# How to use new per pixel SkPhysics Bodies in Sprite kit

Tags: ios, iphone, sprite-kit, skphysicsbody

Withe the release of iOS 8 apple also released the new swift. Buy they also released some updates to sprite kit. One of them being per pixel physics bodies. I was trying to find how to implement this per pixel physics bodies in xcode beta and after searching through the SKphysicBody class i couldn't fine anything. Just wondering if this will be released later on or if i have missed something.Also if this feature is only available in swift or if it available in both swift and objective C.

Comment: you probably weren't looking in the prerelease documentation respectively the Xcode 6 documentation

Comment: do you know where i might find this?

Comment: Don't worry i found it...you were right i was looking in the wrong documentation. you use bodywithtexture :) Thanks for you help!

Comment: @ObjectiveCsam - Could you link us to it?  I'm looking for the same thing and it would help anyone who stumbles across this post, if you could post a link to the documentation you found.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For per pixel physics bodies

SWIFT

`init(texture texture: SKTexture!, size size: CGSize) -> SKPhysicsBody`

OBJECTIVE-C

`+ (SKPhysicsBody *)bodyWithTexture:(SKTexture *)texture
                               size:(CGSize)size`